# Alternative source for instructions of LEGO set 7784 Batmobile?

Tags: instructions

The PDF instructions provided on the LEGO website are of very low quality. With all the black pieces, no contours can be identified. I bought a used 7784 without original instructions and with some missing part and have difficulties finding what is actually missing.

The set is almost complete, only this area is incomplete:
[image]

Is there an alternative source for LEGO instructions, possibly by a community that addresses this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those instructions are indeed of low quality. I haven't found a downloadable copy of better quality than that either.

Unless you can find someone with a physical copy that is willing to scan them for you, or can convince the Lego company to dig you up a higher quality pdf, your best option appears to be buying a physical copy on the secondary market, like on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?I=7784-1) or [Brickowl](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-the-batmobile-ultimate-collectors-edition-set-7784-instructions) eg.

As an alternative, there are some Youtube videos showing the full instructions, if that's up your alley. Just look for "lego 7784 instructions".

On the other hand, your question does make it seem like you're really interested in the list of parts, and not so much the building instructions. In that case, there are several websites that can provide that information. A selection :

- [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7784-1#T=I)
- [Brickowl](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-the-batmobile-ultimate-collectors-edition-set-7784#inventory)
- [Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/7784-1/The-Batmobile-Ultimate-Collectors-Edition)
- [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/sets/7784-1/the-batmobile-ultimate-collectors-edition/#parts)

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Actually, I am looking for clear images of that section (I added a photo in the question). Then I may be able to complete the set. One of the YT videos is a speed build. I will have a closer look.

Comment: @Aziraphale : ah - in that case, [LegoFan's answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/17564/19372) is probably more appropriate. Comparing your physical model against the digital model(s) mentioned in that answer sounds easier than watching through a youtube video.

Comment: For this particular case, the speed build video was the quickest solution. The set came fully assembled, but with 2-3 parts missing PLUS a simple building error that I hadn't figured out so far. It seems that I only need 2 of those black 1x3 curved slopes to have a complete 7784. Yippieh!

Comment: For reference, the instructions on the LEGO Builder app are just as bad.

Answer (score 7):

There are people who do an awesome job and [remake entire sets in LEGO Digital Designer.](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/41226-key-topic-official-lego-sets-made-in-ldd)

Luckily they did your model too:

https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&view=findpost&p=1097640

https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&view=findpost&p=909795

Comment: You may try [LeoCAD](https://www.leocad.org/), opensource tool for LEGO designing, that supports `.lxf` files provided at forum.

Comment: Very interesting. As I understand, LDD is no longer supported and LDraw/LeoCAD have similar functionality? I only installed stud.io once, but I never really used digital LEGO desingning. For a quick solution for my question, I found @Sander D Dycker's answer very useful. Thank you anyway for showing the LeoCAD solution, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: Note that Stud.io can also load lxf files.

Comment: @Aziraphale Yes, LDD is not supported anymore (this means LEGO will not add new bricks, etc.), but works and can be downloaded from 3rd party sources. In this case, with digital designer tools you can explore model brick by brick, including part numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This is to wrap up this question. I accepted @Sander De Dycker's answer because it directly led to the solution. The images show the critical section of the crappy official PDF plus a screenshot from a speed build video.

[image: before]

[image: after]

[image: image from speed build]